# Map and fold a collection in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

I have a `fold` which iterates through elements, dependently modifies them one by one and at the same time modifies their parent.

Currently I replace the elements in their parent one by one in the `fold`, they are just few and it is not a real performance issue, but I wonder if there is perhaps a nicer way to express this.

```
case class Behavior(x: Int) {
  def simulate(s: Entity): Behavior = copy(x = x + (if (s.alternate) 2 else 1))
}

case class Entity(alternate: Boolean, behaviors: List[Behavior]) {
  def replaceBehavior(o: Behavior, n: Behavior): Entity = {
    copy(behaviors = behaviors.patch(behaviors.indexOf(o), Seq(n), 1))
  }
  def toggleAlternate: Entity = copy(alternate = !alternate)

  def simulate: Entity = {
    behaviors.foldLeft(this) { (e, b) =>
      e.replaceBehavior(b, b.simulate(e)).toggleAlternate
    }    
  }
}

val entity = Entity(false, List(Behavior(10), Behavior(20), Behavior(30)))

entity.simulate
```

Is there some operation or perhaps some clever use of `scan` or something like that which would allow me to perform `foldLeft` and `map` dependent of the `foldLeft` result in one step? (I would prefer vanilla standard Scala library, but using functional frameworks is possible too).

Comment: In the real code, does `toggleAlternate` read the behaviors at all?

Comment: In the real code `b.simulate` produces both updated `Behavior` and updated `Entity`

Answer (score 2):

Folds (`fold`, `foldLeft`, `foldRight`, ...) usually turn some `Collection[A]` into `B`.

You could map over `A` before folding result to `B` - `foldMap` maps `A => B` and assumed existence of `Monoid[B]` (this is available in Cats in `Foldable` typeclass), so you would perform transformation `Collection[A] --using f--> Collection[B] --using Monoid[B]--> B` (code can optimize it to perform things in one step using e.g. `foldLeft` internally).

Reversing the order of operations - we `fold` and then we `map` - is in general impossible because there is nothing that can let us assume that after `fold` step we will end up with something that is a `Functor`.

Depending on your specific use case we might try using `foldMap` to achieve your goal.

Comment: "Collection[A] --using f--> Collection[B] --using Monoid[B]--> B" I have to admit I do not understand what this means. What is `--using`? This does not look like a Scala operators - is this some kind of a symbolic pseudocode notation?

Comment: It's a pseudocode for `A ---> B` with what is used to perform step (function `f`, `Monoid[B]`) written on the arrow.